# Hide URL in my website

Tags: php, .htaccess

Need to hide this URL

```
http://localhost:8080/Gamesite/details.php?id=1
```

To this URL

```
http://localhost:8080/Gamesite/details.php
```

already have a 404 redirect in .htaccess that looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost:8080/Gamesite/core/404.html
```

but it will only redirect if I change anything that is before the (?) in the url

I GOT IT TO WORK

Comment: No, I just get the game id from the database, then display it in the details.php page. For example for game id 1, it would be details.php?id=1 // Get the product ID
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "select * from games where id = '$id'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$game = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: sorry for the mess, cant create a new line, cause it submits the comment

Comment: Based on your code, you are using GET method, so it displays in the url bar..use POST method instead.

Comment: cant use post, because I have to GET the ID from the database like this:       $id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "select * from games where id = '$id'";                                                           if i do POST, $id will be undifined

Comment: I got it u guys!!, what i did was i grabbed the id, queried to see if id existed in database by doing a mysqli_num_rows. Then did:       if ($count == 0) { header('Location: core/404.html');

Answer (score 1):

To hide the parameters We basically use `POST` method to hide, It ll send the data to your servlet using `requestHeader`, If you are using form to submit the data use attribute `method = "POST"`

Comment: Im just getting information from the database, then displaying it in details.php

Comment: Then from where it is taking id value as 1

Comment: i am asking, how you are getting this request from another anchr tag or through any form submission

Comment: $id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "select * from games where id = '$id'";

Comment: Sorry to say this. I dont know about the PHP., but here you are using $id = $_GET['id']; instead of this is $id = $_POST['id'];